# BackoffCriteria not working for WorkManager Worker class and getRunAttemptCount not increasing

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using WorkMangaer and setting a backoffCriteria, but when I run it the backoff policy does not seem to work and the getRunAttemptCount does not increase:

Here are the results in the logcat, which are not happening every 10 seconds or according to the backoff policy I specified:

```
2022-03-05 12:11:56.705 doWork: for 22f6d39e-7404-4efb-ba13-ccb468fdcb5d attempt 0
2022-03-05 12:11:56.787 doWork.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.5:5001
2022-03-05 12:11:56.787 doWork: for 22f6d39e-7404-4efb-ba13-ccb468fdcb5d attempt 0
2022-03-05 12:11:56.872 doWork.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.5:5001
2022-03-05 12:11:56.872 doWork: for 22f6d39e-7404-4efb-ba13-ccb468fdcb5d attempt 0
2022-03-05 12:11:56.952 doWork.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.5:5001
2022-03-05 12:11:56.952 doWork: for 22f6d39e-7404-4efb-ba13-ccb468fdcb5d attempt 0
2022-03-05 12:11:57.032 doWork.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.5:5001
2022-03-05 12:11:57.032 doWork: for 22f6d39e-7404-4efb-ba13-ccb468fdcb5d attempt 0
2022-03-05 12:11:57.116 doWork.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.5:5001
2022-03-05 12:11:57.116 doWork: for 22f6d39e-7404-4efb-ba13-ccb468fdcb5d attempt 0
2022-03-05 12:11:57.206 doWork.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.5:5001
2022-03-05 12:11:57.206 doWork: for 22f6d39e-7404-4efb-ba13-ccb468fdcb5d attempt 0
2022-03-05 12:11:57.295 doWork.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.5:5001
2022-03-05 12:11:57.295 doWork: for 22f6d39e-7404-4efb-ba13-ccb468fdcb5d attempt 0
2022-03-05 12:11:57.377 doWork.IOException: Failed to connect to /10.0.0.5:5001
```

Here is the code I am using to enqueue the work. I've tried both LINEAR and EXPONENTIAL with the same result and increased the backoffDelay and used both duration and delay + time unit as specified [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#retries_backoff):

```
    WorkManager
            .getInstance(context)
            .cancelAllWorkByTag(sb.toString());

    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresCharging(false)
            .build();

    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(worker)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .addTag(sb.toString())
            .setInputData(data)
            .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL,10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    WorkManager
            .getInstance(context)
            .enqueueUniqueWork(sb.toString(),REPLACE,oneTimeWorkRequest)
            .getResult();
```

Here is the doWork method. The error is getting trapped and I am returning Result.Retry() so:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {

    //get the id of the scenario
    Log.d(TAG, "doWork: for " + getId() + " attempt " + getRunAttemptCount());

    int scenarioRunId = getInputData().getInt(INPUT_DATA_SCENARIORUNID, -1);

    CloudSync cloudSync = new CloudSync.Builder()
            .setContext(context)
            .build();

    try {

        cloudSync.syncScenarioRun(scenarioRunId);
        return Result.success();

    } catch (MsalException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "doWork.MsalException: " + e.getMessage());
        TelemetryObject.TrackError(context, e, TAG, doWork().toString());
        return Result.retry();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "doWork.InterruptedException: " + e.getMessage());
        TelemetryObject.TrackError(context, e, TAG, doWork().toString());
        return Result.retry();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "doWork.IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        TelemetryObject.TrackError(context, e, TAG, doWork().toString());
        return Result.retry();

    } catch (WebApiException e) {

        Log.d(TAG, "doWork.WebApiException: " + e.getMessage());
        TelemetryObject.TrackError(context, e, TAG, doWork().toString());
        return Result.retry();

    }
}
```

According to the documentation the Results.retry(), which I am calling, should trigger the backoff backoff behavior I specify, but it is not:

> In this example, the minimum backoff delay is set to the minimum
> allowed value, 10 seconds. Since the policy is LINEAR the retry
> interval will increase by approximately 10 seconds with each new
> attempt. For instance, the first run finishing with Result.retry()
> will be attempted again after 10 seconds, followed by 20, 30, 40, and
> so on, if the work continues to return Result.retry() after subsequent
> attempts. If the backoff policy were set to EXPONENTIAL, the retry
> duration sequence would be closer to 20, 40, 80, and so on.

This is driving me a little crazy because I need to schedule multiple of these objects and can't if it's so chatty and there is no limit to retries, so I need the getRunAttemptCount to work. I'm really stuck. I don't know if I am doing it wrong or there is a bug. I been over and over it, but there is not a lot of code to really check.

**UPDATE**

I created a way to test the worker alone and the BackoffCriteria and getRunAttemptCount are working.

```
2022-03-08 07:46:55.515 doWork.workerTest: attempt=0 time=2022.03.08 AD at 07:46:55 EST
2022-03-08 07:47:05.573 doWork.workerTest: attempt=1 time=2022.03.08 AD at 07:47:05 EST
2022-03-08 07:47:25.618 doWork.workerTest: attempt=2 time=2022.03.08 AD at 07:47:25 EST
2022-03-08 07:48:05.679 doWork.workerTest: attempt=3 time=2022.03.08 AD at 07:48:05 EST
```

which means it must be something in the work I am doing which is causing the problem. I am getting data from a Room database, calling a webapi with retrofit, and updating the data in the database.

Must be something to do with the threading.